# ionic login with facebook using firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, facebook, angularfire

i used to have a working code but recently it is broken with auth() not recognized etc.

current broken code is:

```
import { Facebook } from '@ionic-native/facebook/ngx'
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    public fb:Facebook,
  )

login(){
    if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
      return this.fb.login(['email', 'public_profile']).then(res => {
        const facebookCredential = firebase.auth().FacebookAuthProvider.credential(res.authResponse.accessToken);
         firebase.auth.signInWithCredential(facebookCredential);
      }).catch(err)
    }
```

in the above code auth() is not recognized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you upgrade to v9 of the Firebase JavaScript SDKs by any chance or to version 7 of AngularFire?

If so, see the [AngularFire v7 upgrade guide](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/version-7-upgrade.md) and the [Firebase JS v9 upgrade guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade).